# Override default function in typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have made this button class in typescript. I have given it a "default" function to handle click events. But what if i instead want to be to pass a function as an argument and call the passed one on click instead?

Here the code:

```
abstract class BaseButton {

  element:HTMLElement;
  label:string;

  constructor(element:HTMLElement, label:string) {
    console.log(this);
    this.element = element;
    this.label = label;
    this.init();
  }

  init():void {
    this.setText(this.label);
    this.addListeners();
  }

  setText(label:string):void {
    this.element.innerHTML = label;
  }

  kill():void {
    this.removeListeners();
  }

  addListeners():void {
    this.element.addEventListener("mouseover", this.onMouseOver);
    this.element.addEventListener("click", this.onClick);
    this.element.addEventListener("mouseout", this.onMouseOut);
    this.element.addEventListener('touchstart', this.onTouchStart);
    this.element.addEventListener('touchmove', this.onTouchMove);
    this.element.addEventListener('touchcancel', this.onTouchCancel);
    this.element.addEventListener('touchend', this.onTouchEnd);
  }

  removeListeners():void {
    this.element.removeEventListener("mouseover", this.onMouseOver);
    this.element.removeEventListener("click", this.onClick);
    this.element.removeEventListener("mouseout", this.onMouseOut);
    this.element.removeEventListener('touchstart', this.onTouchStart);
    this.element.removeEventListener('touchmove', this.onTouchMove);
    this.element.removeEventListener('touchcancel', this.onTouchCancel);
    this.element.removeEventListener('touchend', this.onTouchEnd);
  }

  onTouchStart():void {

  }

  onTouchMove():void {

  }

  onTouchCancel():void {

  }

  onTouchEnd():void {

  }

  onMouseOver():void {
    console.log('mouse over');
  }

  onMouseOut():void {
    console.log('mouse out');
  }

  abstract onClick(event:Event):void
}

class Button extends BaseButton {

  element:HTMLElement;
  label:string;
  callback:any;

  constructor(element:HTMLElement, label:string, callback?: () => void) {
    super(element,label);
    this.element = element;
    this.label = label;
    this.callback = callback;
  }

  onClick(event:Event):void {
    if (this.callback) {
      console.log('ddd');
      this.callback();
    }
  }  
}





const el = document.getElementById('btn');
const button = new Button(el,'Click');

const ell = document.getElementById('btnn');
const buttonn = new Button(ell,'Click');

const elll = document.getElementById('btnnn');
const buttonnn = new Button(elll,'Click', () => {
  alert('fff');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are losing the `this` reference inside of the `onClick` function of the subclass when the following event handler runs in the base class:

```
this.element.addEventListener("click", this.onClick)
```

Normally this could be solved by using an arrow function:

```
class Button extends BaseButton {
  constructor(element: HTMLElement, label: string, private callback?: () => void) {
    super(element, label);
  }

  onClick = (event: Event) => {
    if (this.callback) {
      this.callback();
    }
  }
}
```

But in this particular case you'll get the following error if you try to define it in the subclass:

> Class 'BaseButton' defines instance member function 'onClick', but
>   extended class 'Button' defines it as instance member property.

And if you try to define an `onClick` arrow function in the subclass's constructor:

```
class Button extends BaseButton {
  constructor(element: HTMLElement, label: string, private callback?: () => void) {
    super(element, label);

    this.onClick = () => {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get the following error:

> Non-abstract class 'Button' does not implement inherited abstract
>   member 'onClick' from class 'BaseButton'

And if you try to create a stub method just to make the error go away, and create the real method as an arrow function in the constructor:

```
class Button extends BaseButton {
  constructor(element: HTMLElement, label: string, private callback?: () => void) {
    super(element, label);

    this.onClick = () => {
      // ...
    }
  }

  onClick(event: Event) { }
}
```

It won't work because the base class would pass the wrong `onClick` function reference to `addEventListener` because that code runs before the subclass's constructor.

Here is one workaround. Bind `this` in the base class by creating a separate function there which calls `this.onClick()`, and keep a reference to that new function so you can de-register it.

```
abstract class BaseButton {
  private onClickBound;

  constructor(protected element: HTMLElement, protected label: string) {
    this.init();
  }

  init(): void {
    this.addListeners();
  }

  kill(): void {
    this.removeListeners();
  }

  addListeners(): void {
    this.onClickBound = (e: Event) => this.onClick(e);

    // Or you can do this:
    // this.onClickBound = this.onClick.bind(this)

    this.element.addEventListener("click", this.onClickBound);
  }

  removeListeners(): void {
    this.element.removeEventListener("click", this.onClickBound);
  }

  abstract onClick(event: Event);
}

class Button extends BaseButton {
  constructor(element: HTMLElement, label: string, private callback?: () => void) {
    super(element, label);
  }

  onClick(event: Event) {
    if (this.callback) {
      this.callback();
    }
  }
}
```

I'll try to come up with a cleaner solution as I'm not crazy about this one.

Comment: Hi, thank you! Maybe i was not clear enought. What i want to do is to override on click in the Button if a click handler is passed as an argument.

Comment: I believe my code does what you ask. Let me know if you need modifications.

Comment: It gives me the following error: TypeError: this. clickHandler is not a function.

Comment: How are you using it?

Comment: Like this. Pasted the whole thing in a bin. Will edit my post asap. but for now: https://pastebin.com/EZ35kCvh

Comment: Not sure if i should put this here or not. But, what is the main difference between having the parent class as abstract compared to just have it as a "normal" class? Is it just that you can define methods as "abstract" that the child class MUST have? By reading the documentations this is how i understand it.

Comment: That's pretty much it. When you define the class as `abstract`, you can add method definitions without their implementation, and subclasses have to implement them. You cannot instantiate the abstract class, only its subclasses. Also note that abstract methods don't even end up in the compiled JavaScript, since they have no implementation. They are just a concept in TypeScript. Once you implement them, they show up in the compiled JavaScript.

Comment: Oh, Thanks! Thats pretty darn neat.

Comment: I have came acoss a small issue with the code. If i in the abstract class call "this.kill()" from on click (not the passed calback, the one already defined in the abstract class). If i do that "this.kill()" gets undefined. Why is that?

Comment: Does this mean `onClick` is no longer an abstract method? Can you show me a live example?

Answer (score 0):

What if you did something like this (with the rest of your code added)?

```
class Button {
    clickListener; // with any types

    constructor(clickListener = defaultClickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        this.clickListener();
    }
}

function defaultClickListener():void {
    console.log(0);
}

new Button(() => console.log(1));
```